# How to Format the Date in a Kendo Grid In-Cell Edit

Tags: angular, datepicker, kendo-grid

I'm using In-Cell Editing on a `kendo-grid-column`. From the example [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/in-cell-editing/), you can define `editor` attributes to the column. In my column I would like to edit the date and therefore have a date picker for doing so. I can do that by adding the following attribute to the `kendo-grid-column`:

```
editor="date"
```

**My problem is that I would like the date picker formatted to display the YEAR only by using the attribute above.**

*As a side note* - 
this is easily achievable with a `kendoGridCellTemplate` and adding the relevant attributes to format it like this

```
<kendo-grid-column field="FinancialYear" title="Fin Year" width="150">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem  let-column="column">
            <kendo-datepicker style="width: 100%;" id="BudgetedMonth" (click)="cli($event)" (valueChange)="financialYearChange($event)" [value]="displayFinancialYear(dataItem.FinancialYear)" [bottomView]="'decade'" [topView]="'decade'" [format]="'yyyy'"></kendo-datepicker>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

but then I have a problem where the selected row does not immediately trigger the date picker control on selection.

Answer (score 0):

In kendoui for jquery I set the column.format and make sure the data type is set to date for the field in DataSource.schema.model.fields:

kendoGrid

```
var $grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: data,
    editable: "incell",
    columns: [
        {
            field: "Deadline",
            format: "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"
        },
    ...
```

DataSource

```
data: new window.kendo.data.DataSource({
  schema: {
    model: {
      fields: {
        deadline: { type: "date", editable: true }
        ...
```